# How to profile a production ruby on rails app's memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Ruby on Rails app is running on Heroku, with a dyno that has 512 Megabytes of RAM.  It is using almost all the RAM right from app startup, and it only gets worse from there.  I am not loading large amounts of data from the database at startup so do not understand why it is using so much memory.

How do I profile my app in production so I can understand where the memory usage is coming from? I understand that I have the option of adding another dyno or increasing the dyno memory, but I want to understand what is happening first.

Comment: What about `htop`? =)

Comment: I had a look at this, but I use Mac OSX, and htop appears to be buggy for that operating system.

Comment: Are you not able to simulate the leak in dev environments ? How's the memory usage in development env ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has a `log-runtime-metrics` feature to monitor the memory usage.

You can run this to enable that:

```
heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics
```

and the memory usage will be shown on the server log.

See [Heroku Labs: log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics) for more information.

Also, you can use New Relic for the memory profiling.

See the [documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/miscellaneous/ruby-agent-heroku) for more details.

Another awesome resource that I recommend for memory profiling is [rbkit](http://rbkit.codemancers.com/)

Comment: These all are useful.  A good introduction to rbkit is [here](http://rbkit.codemancers.com/docs/getting-started).  Can you safely run rbkit in production?

Comment: @Obromios Rbkit was made to solve precisely this problem you are facing, but it's still not ready for production use since we are actively developing other features like CPU profiling and possibly breaking a lot of things :) (Rbkit developer here)